# Raspberry pi 3 b+ display with the size of car radio

Tags: display, touchscreen

I am working on a car raspberry pi 3 project and i want to replace my car radio with touch screen display, however i can't seem to be able to find the size i need. I can only find 3/3.5/7/10 inches, example of what i am looking - [image: http://infinigeek.com/assets/history-of-car-radio-alpine-car-stereo-receiver-cd.jpg]

the display must be almost as big as this

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there are any touch screens with a 7/2 ratio. The nearest would be something like 3/2 but the only one of those I have seen is actually 60mm high without any trim.